# orbeon form user can submit twice.Can we have a loading indicator for a process in properties-local.xml?

Tags: orbeon

I have an orbeon form which has custom button to submit and The user can submit it twice because there no spinner showing up when he submits and he has ample of time to click the button many times.Can we disable the the submit button when clicked

Visbility formula:xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/*/status!='Submitted' 
form xml:

```
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/cps-submit-btn/label"/>                          

                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/cps-submit-btn/hint"/>                          

                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>                          

                            </xf:trigger>                        

                            <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate" ev:observer="cps-submit-btn-control">                            

                    </xf:action>                        

                            <xf:action xmlns:process="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fr.SimpleProcess" ev:event="DOMActivate" 
                                       ev:observer="cps-submit-btn-control" 
                                       type="xpath">          
                        xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/process:runProcessByName('oxf.fr.detail.process', 'send-CPS')                   


                    </xf:action>
```

Vesrion 4.6PE

Answer (score 0):

Since Orbeon Forms 2016.1 (formerly known as 4.11), you can choose for each button if you'd like to have:

- a spinner inside the button, without blocking user's input, called the inline loading indicator;
- a spinner in the middle of the page, blocking user's input, called the modal loading indicator;
- no spinner at all.

It looks like, for the specific button you're referring to, you are looking for option 2 above. If this is indeed the case, then I would recommend, if possible, to upgradied your Orbeon Forms so you can benefit from this feature.

And for more about this, see the blog post: [How do you tell users "something is going on"?](http://blog.orbeon.com/2016/04/how-do-you-tell-users-something-is.html)

Comment: I have a question.where I have   to specify the type of loading indicator in properties-local file or in form itself?

Comment: @SharathKumarReddyJillela Yes, this is done with the `oxf.fr.detail.loading-indicator.BUTTON.*.*` property, that you define in your `properties-local.xml`. For more on this, see the [documentation for that property](http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#loading-indicator-for-buttons).